# Failure Uninstalling PWA from Android 8

Tags: android, progressive-web-apps

I've developed a PWA - jcoonrod.github.io - when I uninstall it - clear the browser cache  - and then try to go to that page and reinstall it, I only see the old version - the cache seems to outlive the PWA. How can I fully remove cached the files of a PWA on android?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clear the service worker storage, you can do it via Dev Tools of the browser you used, or via code:

```
// To unregister a service worker
navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration()
   .then(function(registration) {
       if(registration){
          registration.unregister()
          .then(
               function(success) {
                 // if success = true, unregister was successful
                });
          }
    });

// To remove the SW storage
if ('caches' in window) {
    caches.keys()
      .then(function(keyList) {
          return Promise.all(keyList.map(function(key) {
              return caches.delete(key);
          }));
      })
}
```

The caches.keys() method returns the keys of the CacheStorage, an interface representing the storage for the Cache objects that can be accessed by the service worker.

I wrote [an article about Service Workers and caching strategies](https://dev.to/paco_ita/service-workers-and-caching-strategies-explained-step-3-m4f) and how to clear the stored data, you can have a look at it.

Comment: I guess you don't mean the browser I used on Android, as it has no devtools - you must mean by linking it via USB for remote debugging, as described in https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/ ??

Comment: Yes, I was referring to a "PC" solution, using Dec tools. But the code part apply to any solution.